# Same website, how do I send POST from HTTP to HTTPS? It keeps coming up empty

Tags: php, sql, post, ssl, https

body body body body body body body body body body body body body body

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You could use cUrl instead

Comment: Post your HTML and PHP code.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is that both are being treated as different webservers (well thats actually because they are, even if they are only virtual inside a single apache instance, web browser dosn't know that. )

you should be able to do the post by including the fully qualified name as the form target (e.g.

```
https://www.example.com/myApp/data.php
```

)

simply calling data.php (Even though you are in the myApp folder) will not provide any help.